# Search data from list when user type '@' Symbol in UITextView

Tags: ios, ios8, swift2

Is there any way to show dropdown list when user type "@" with specific search keyword in `UITextView`.

For Example:

Type "@ios" and all the string which contains word "ios" filter from list and show in dropdown list.

Comment: Have a look at the following links and modify according to your requirement.

https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField

https://www.raywenderlich.com/336/auto-complete-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by constantly checking user type text.

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    // if user type any latter from @,space and new line then clear the search string
    if text == "@" || text == " " || text == "\n" {
        self.searchString = ""
    }
    // append the type string in text view text
    let resultString = textView.text.stringByAppendingString(text)
    // break the line with @ symbol and find the occurence
    let numberOfOccurrences = resultString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "@")).count - 1
    // store all words for checking
    let stringArray = resultString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "@")) ?? [String]()
    // checking if string array > 1 that means string contains @ symbol
    self.searchString = stringArray.count > 1 ? stringArray[numberOfOccurrences].containsString(" ") ? "" : stringArray[numberOfOccurrences] : ""
    if self.searchString.characters.count > 0 {
        self.getTopSearchFromLive(self.searchString)
    } else {
        self.tableView.hidden = true
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this.This delegate will be called whenever a user presses @ key

Try this :-

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if (textView.text.appending(text) == "@") {
        //trigger '@' operation
        if arrayObject.contains(value) {
            //Populate array and display tableview.
        }
    }
    else if (textView.text.appending(text) == "/") {
        //trigger / operation
    }
    //Same conditions go on
}
```